# Pyspark rdd operations! (Python3, Spark2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an 'input.txt' file containing the following:

```
[10,21,90,34,40,98,21,44,59,21,90,34,29,19, 21,90,34,29,49,78 ]
```

As I'm a beginner, I'm trying to perform the following on the above file using RDD operations. (I was able to perform it by copying the RDD elements to a list):

- I want to display the above given list and the first element of the list.
- I want to display the sorted output (ascending and descending) through an RDD and display the distinct elements of the list using an RDD.
- Display maximum and minimum of given list.
- Combine above list with a new input in the form: `{30,35,45,60,75,85}` and display output.
- Provide the sum of the list elements using reduce with distinct values.
- Provide the sum of the list elements using reduce.

Can I do all of the above tasks using Pyspark actions and transformations or am I being too ambitious? Apologies for so many questions. I've been into spark for only a week.

### EDIT

I don't want to hard code the list in my code. 
I want to read the file (input.txt). 
I tried using

```
data = sc.textFile("./input.txt")
collected = data.collect()
print(data)
d2 = d1[0].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
print(d2)
```

But using this approach, I'm unable to transform the rdd into a List of Int without converting it into a normal Python List ( d3 = d2.strip("{}").split(',') ).

I'm unable to get tha max using either max(d2) or d2.max() as it says max is unspported.

I hope I'm making myself clear now!

Answer (score 2):

First, get the data into RDD:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([10,21,90,34,40,98,21,44,59,21,90,34,29,19, 21,90,34,29,49,78])
```

Display the above given list and the first element of the list.

```
rdd.collect()
rdd.take(1)
```

Also I want to display the sorted output (ascending and descending) through an RDD and display the distinct elements of the list using an RDD.

```
rdd.distinct().sortBy(lambda x:x).collect()
rdd.distinct().sortBy(lambda x:-x).collect()
```

Display maximum and minimum of given list.

```
rdd.max()
rdd.min()
```

Combine above list with a new input in the form: { 30,35,45,60,75,85} and display output.

```
newrdd = sc.parallelize({30,35,45,60,75,85})
rdd.union(newrdd).collect()
```

Provide the sum of the list elements using reduce with distinct values.

```
rdd.distinct().reduce(lambda x,y:x+y)
```

Provide the sum of the list elements using reduce.

```
rdd.reduce(lambda x,y:x+y)
```

P.S.
In fact, if you sort your element in rdd descending, the max element is the first element of this rdd. So, You can get the max of this rdd **without** using `max()`, so, this is the code:

```
rdd.distinct().sortBy(lambda x:-x).take(1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
But I don't want to hard code the list in my code. 
I want to read the file (input.txt). 
I tried using 

    data = sc.textFile("./input.txt")
    collected = data.collect()
    print(data)
    d2 = d1[0].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    print(d2)


But using this approach, I'm unable to transform the rdd into a List of Int without converting it into a normal Python List ( d3 = d2.strip("{}").split(',') ). I'm unable to get tha max using either max(d2) or d2.max() as it says max is unspported. 

I hope I'm making myself clear now!

Comment: If you cannot use `max()`, you can just sort it and take the first element.

Comment: Hi @iPrince! I used sorted() then take() to do the same. Is there a better method?